# clientProgramName equiavlent property in ComboPooledDataSource(c3p0)

Tags: jdbc, db2, c3p0

We are using ComboPooledDataSource(c3p0) for db2 connection pooling. We have monitoring tool that expects [clientProgramName](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_r0021822.html) property of DB2BaseDataSource to be set in order to filter the queries by program name.

Does any one know if ComboPooledDataSource  has equivalent property of clientProgramName ? or what property needs to be set in ComboPooledDataSource, so that it will send application name to db2 server?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the 'key=value' pair to you connection string.

```
"...;clientProgramName=mySuperJdbcApp;"
```

Comment: We must close any property value with `;`. So, it must be `"...;clientProgramName=mySuperJdbcApp;"`